# applicationDidEnterBackground: Issue

Tags: xcode, background, simulator

I wrote an app that has about 3 different view controllers for each view in the tab bar. I called applicationDidEnterBackground: in each of the view controllers to save all the data in that specific view after the home button is tapped. This runs flawlessly on the iPad simulator, but for some reason, it crashed after trying to edit the data on the iPhone simulator. I thought this is probably an issue with putting the applicationDidEnterBackground: in the view controller, but if that was the issue, then wouldn't it crash on the iPad simulator as well?

I know that I should put applicationDidEnterBackground in the app delegate, but my method looks sort of like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [array addObject:firstField.text];
    [array addObject:secondField.text];

    [array writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
}
```

If I put this in the App Delegate, of course it doesn't recognize firstField or secondField because I did not declare it in header file or synthesize it or anything. If I were to declare everything in the App Delegate, then the outlets in my nib file will fail because each of the File's Owner's class is one of those specific view controllers.

Is the placement of applicationDidEnterBackground: not even my issue since it runs fine on the iPad simulator?
Also, it used to run fine on the iPhone simulator as well. I changed the Image View's background on all of the nibs, then this started happening. I rechecked all my outlets and actions and they match up fine.

EDIT: I fixed it. Turns out I had an extra field that I decided to add to the iPad's nib, but not the iPhone's. I though it would be fine, not the case though. That explains all the weirdness that was going on. I deleted the field in the iPad's nib and everything is A Okay. Phillipe, thank you so much for your help and offer to look it over for me, that is incredibly generous.

Comment: applicationDidEnterBackground should only be called on the App Delegate. Are you sure those methods are being called on your view controllers? Are you calling them specifically from your app delegate on each controller? Set breakpoints on each and see if they're actually being called in either case.

Comment: Thanks. Yes they are being called in each of the view controllers, it was the only way that I could think of to include all of the outlets in that view without any errors. The applicationDidEnterBackground field is left blank in the main App Delegate. Could this be the issue, even though it works fine in the iPad simulator?

Comment: I'm confused as to how those methods are even being called as they should only be called on the App's delegate. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html Maybe you could send your project zipped to my email (in profile) and I could take a look at it for you.

Comment: @Philippe Sabourin Thank you so much! You are a life saver, I can't thank you enough. I'm trying to find your email address in your profile but its not displaying it in your bio section. Just a link to your website. It doesn't look like I can private message you on here either, could you possibly throw your email in your about me section for a few? That is incredibly generous, I would be more then happy to pay you a bit through paypal for your effort man.

Comment: I fixed it. Turns out I had an extra field that I decided to add to the iPad's nib, but not the iPhone's. I though it would be fine, not the case though. That explains all the weirdness that was going on. I deleted the field in the iPad's nib and everything is A Okay. Phillipe, thank you so much for your help and offer to look it over for me, that is incredibly generous.

Comment: Alright, sounds good. Sorry, I thought my email shows up for everyone. Thanks for the heads up on that. Good job figuring it out. I'm still surprised that those methods are called though, maybe you have it linked somehow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. Turns out I had an extra field that I decided to add to the iPad's nib, but not the iPhone's. I though it would be fine, not the case though. That explains all the weirdness that was going on. I deleted the field in the iPad's nib and everything is A Okay. Phillipe, thank you so much for your help and offer to look it over for me, that is incredibly generous.